# SQL0903N COMMIT statement failed, transaction rolled back in db2luw

Tags: db2

I am working on Db2 ATS jobs. 
This is what I have tried. Created one procedure p1 on database d1.This procedure will update a table t1 on database d1.From the procedure p1 on a direct call i can update table t1.
And now I have created one table t2 on database d2. From database d1 I am trying to update this table t2 . This is also working fine.
From the database d1 I can update the two tables t1 & t2.

Now I tried the same with a ATS jobs.
I can submit a job to call procedure p1 to update table t1 on database d1 .The job is working fine & able to view the updated records.

tried to submit a job from d1 which will update a table t2 on database d2.
Job is running fine without any error. But the table is not updating.

Below is my procedure & logs Can some one tell me what I am missing here:

```
CREATE or REPLACE PROCEDURE D_JUMP12(IN text VARCHAR(32672))
p1:BEGIN
DECLARE jobno   NUMBER;
execute IMMEDIATE TEXT; 
COMMIT;
END p1
```

This is the way I am calling the procedure:

```
call DBMS_JOB.SUBMIT (?, 'CALL D_JUMP12(''UPDATE sample.reg.CABS SET FIRSTNAME = reg_f_fixed_char_repos(FIRSTNAME)'')',NULL);
```

These are my logs:

```
2015-03-17-18.37.10.360000+330 E110713390F554       LEVEL: Error
PID     : 2460                 TID : 444            PROC : db2fmp64.exe
INSTANCE: DB2                  NODE : 000           DB   : test1
APPID   : *LOCAL.DB2.150317130717
HOSTNAME: MANGO-04
EDUID   : 444
FUNCTION: DB2 UDB, Administrative Task Scheduler, AtsConnection::commit,   probe:900
MESSAGE : ECF=0x82BA00E1=-2101739295
DATA #1 : String, 124 bytes
```

[IBM][CLI Driver][DB2/NT64] SQL0903N  COMMIT statement failed, transaction    rolled back.  Reason code: "2".  SQLSTATE=40504

```
2015-03-17-18.37.10.364000+330 I110713946F425       LEVEL: Error
PID     : 2460                 TID : 444            PROC : db2fmp64.exe
INSTANCE: DB2                  NODE : 000           DB   : test1
APPID   : *LOCAL.DB2.150317130717
HOSTNAME: MANGO-04
EDUID   : 444
FUNCTION: DB2 UDB, Administrative Task Scheduler, AtsTask::run, probe:1300
MESSAGE : ECF=0x82BA00E1=-2101739295
DATA #1 : Codepath, 8 bytes 
4
```

Kindly let me know what I am missing here

Comment: Can some one Help me with this . Is this a bug ?

Comment: See this link: http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_9.5.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.messages.sql.doc/doc/msql00903n.html